# Waiter for R shiny not showing properly when using it on renders of different tabPanel

Tags: r, shiny, tabs, spinner, render

I have an issue with the `waiter` which I need for an app built with `R` `shiny`.

The example below (based on the fantastic website on the `waiter` package by John Coene: https://waiter.john-coene.com/#/waiter/examples#on-render) helps me illustrate my issue.

The app is made of two `tabPanel`s, the first one which shows a table, and the second one that shows a chart. The table and the chart will appear after some waiting time, and the waiter spinner should, in the meantime, appear in the middle of the rendering areas of both `tabPanel`s.

However, what actually happen is that the waiter spinner only shows up in the middle of the rendering area of the `tabPanel` I open first, whereas in the other `tabPanel` it is stuck in the top-left corner of the page.

Many thanks in advance for whoever can help me fix this problem!

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(shinythemes)
library(waiter)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cyborg"),

  useWaiter(),

  actionButton("draw", "render stuff"),

  fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table")),
      tabPanel("Chart", highchartOutput("hc"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  # specify the id 
  w <- Waiter$new(id = c("hc", "table"))
  
  dataset <- reactive({
    input$draw
    
    w$show()
    
    Sys.sleep(8)
    
    head(cars)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable(dataset())

  output$hc <- renderHighchart({
    hchart(dataset(), "scatter", hcaes(speed, dist))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you use `shinycssloaders` instead. The reason is that loaders' positions in `waiter` are calculated by current visible height and width. However, there is no visible position in the second tab or the hidden tabs, so `waiter` can't add the loader to the right spot. There is no fix we can do here. This is a feature that `waiter` doesn't support currently.

```r
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinycssloaders)

ui <- fluidPage(
    theme = shinytheme("cyborg"),
    actionButton("draw", "render stuff"),
    fluidPage(
        tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("Table", withSpinner(tableOutput("table"), type = 3, color.background = "#060606", color = "#EEEEEE")),
            tabPanel("Chart", withSpinner(highchartOutput("hc"), type = 3, color.background = "#060606", color = "#EEEEEE"))
        )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output){
    dataset <- reactive({
        input$draw
        Sys.sleep(4)
        head(cars)
    })
    output$table <- renderTable(dataset())
    output$hc <- renderHighchart({
        hchart(dataset(), "scatter", hcaes(speed, dist))
    })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]